# Need help installing Windows 10 dev channel version 21390.1, getting error 0x800705aa, suggestions?

Tags: windows-update, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-preview

zThe system reboots fine, but the update is not installed listing the above error code.  I have tried suggestions from various sites on potential remedies, but no luck so far.

In particular, I have tried:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanupimage /restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

No errors reported.

Doing a clean boot.  Turning off all non-microsoft services and all startup programs.

No effect from doing that either.

I am currently running 21H1 from the beta channel (installed about a week ago)

[image]

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H1
Installed on    ‎11/‎5/‎2020
OS build    19043.1023
Serial number   PF28VDHL
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0
```

My insider account is now set to the dev channel.

---

I want this version to use WSL 2 with support for graphic applications (to run Emacs without vcXserv).

---

The computer has tried ~6 times to install this update, so it is not a transient problem.  It reports no errors while downloading the update (nor while restarting).

---

By the way, I have tried all the steps listed in:

https://softwaretested.com/mac/how-to-fix-the-error-0x800705aa-on-windows-10/

I have 77 GB free on my Windows partition.  I have run disk cleanup on the partition.

I don't have a third party AV running.

There are no peripherals to disconnect, no SD card.

The download reports no errors and gives me a nice prompt to install the new feature version.  And it restarts just fine with nice xx% messages about progress, but after rebooting when I check windows update, it says it failed with the above error.

The "windows update troubleshooter" says:

Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem.

---

Comment: Try re-running the DISM command as dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth .  The command you ran was dsim and likely did not do anything.  My insider machine is running the version you want to get to.

Comment: Actually, I ran dism.exe.  I just typed it wrong in my message.  And, I was running it as administrator.

Comment: Try the Windows Update Troubleshooting steps. Article here describes that:   https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/how-to-fix-the-error-0x800705aa-on-windows-10.459045/

Comment: “I am currently running 21H1 from the beta channel.” - 21H1 is no longer in the Beta channel.  Can you provide the exact build you are running since it’s not the 21H1 build? 21390 is in the Dev channel.

Comment: I do not see 21H1 but I am in the Dev channel and version shows as 21390.1

Comment: I pasted my update history and the "about" information.

Comment: The troubleshooter couldn't identify the problem.....

Comment: I have increase the partition so that it now has 77 GB free (up from 10GB when I started and 19 when I posted this question.  Hasn't helped.

Comment: SetupDiag should provide insight into the failure; This failure isn’t a free space issue; Have you tried using a Insider Preview build ISO to upgrade what appears to be a stable channel build to a unstable Dev build?

Comment: I tried increasing the freespace because on the Microsoft community, that was suggested as a possible issue.

Comment: Setupdiag crashes  (and I have version 4.6 of .net installed)


PS C:\Windows\system32> c:\users\cfclark\documents\setupdiag.exe

SetupDiag v1.6.1.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Internal.Deployment.SetupDiag.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Where do I find information on installing via an ISO image.  I've done that for Linux before but not for Win 10.  I don't have a CD drive or a thumb drive handy, but can get one on Tuesday.

Comment: I have version 4.6 of .net installed)   <-- That is a long way back. Can you update it to 4.8?  Look in optional updates.

Comment: It said it required 4.6, I actually have 4.8.04084 installed.

Comment: Ok, it is almost 1:30am here, so I am quitting for the night.  I will be traveling most of tomorrow, so I won't do anything until late (my time).

Comment: It's impossible for Windows 10 to have .NET Framework 4.6 installed.  21H1 has .NET Framework 4.8 built-in, it is literally impossible, to install .NET 4.6 on your system.  An application that requires 4.6 will run on your system, if SetupDiag is crashing, it's not due to you having .NET Framework 4.8 installed.  I was able to run SetupDiag on my 21H1 system without a problem.

Comment: Yes, I have .NET 4.8.04084 installed.  I thought, I had 4.6, because when I tried to install it (after the setdiag failed to run), it said I already had it installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by @ramhound to try doing an ISO installation was the path to the solution.

I downloaded the dev channel version (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso), it was older than the one I wanted, but after installing it, windows update was able to install the version I wanted.